# How to assign values to variables in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a  field named  Datavalue 2, I have to manually assign value to that field,How do I write the calculations for this. Any leads for this will be helpful.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Tableau is a read-only tool. It does not allow you to make **persistent** modifications to the original source data.

If you want to derive a value of a field that can change during the life of a Tableau visualization, but leave the original data source unchanged, that is entirely possible. The Tableau features that help with this are calculated fields and parameters. Parameters can be set interactively by the user. Both features are documented in the on-line help.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau has some tricky issues with it, but it is possible to work with variables as well. I am making the assumption that your data is connected through a database.

In my experience, I was connected with data from an MSSQL server, and I had need to use variables for some data cleaning.

The solution I came upon was the difference between using a 'Custom SQL Query' and 'Initial SQL'.

Tableau will not allow declared variables, temp tables, or common table expressions in 'Custom SQL' but it will allow all of those items in the 'Initial SQL' area.

Under 'Connections' Tableau should have the server connection, right clicking on this will allow you to navigate to the 'Initial SQL' box.

After that, I had to do a little fidgeting with the code, but ultimately it was a successful process. Hope that helps somewhat to the OP or any newer viewers. There weren't quite enough tags to determine more about the issue.